# "no suitable method found" while trying to implement a custom binding

Tags: jooq

I got the following message trying to create a custom binding for Postgres ltrees:

```
[...]/jooq/routines/JSubpath1.java:37: error: no suitable method found for createParameter(String,DataType<Integer>,boolean,boolean,LtreeBinding)
    public static final Parameter<String> _2 = Internal.createParameter("_2", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.INTEGER, false, true, new LtreeBinding());
                                                       ^
    method Internal.<T#1>createParameter(String,DataType<T#1>,boolean,boolean) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#1
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method Internal.<T#2,U#1>createParameter(String,DataType<T#2>,boolean,boolean,Converter<T#2,U#1>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2,U#1
        (argument mismatch; LtreeBinding cannot be converted to Converter<T#2,U#1>))
    method Internal.<T#3,U#2>createParameter(String,DataType<T#3>,boolean,boolean,Binding<T#3,U#2>) is not applicable
      (inference variable T#3 has incompatible equality constraints Object,Integer)
    method Internal.<T#4,X,U#3>createParameter(String,DataType<T#4>,boolean,boolean,Converter<X,U#3>,Binding<T#4,X>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#4,X,U#3
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
```

Here's the binding:

```
class LtreeBinding : Binding<Any, String> {

    override fun converter(): Converter<Any, String> {
        return object : Converter<Any, String> {
            override fun from(dbAny: Any?): String? {
                return dbAny?.toString()
            }

            override fun to(userAny: String?): Any? {
                return userAny as Any
            }

            override fun fromType(): Class<Any> {
                return Any::class.java
            }

            override fun toType(): Class<String> {
                return String::class.java
            }
        }
    }

    override fun sql(ctx: BindingSQLContext<String>) {
        ctx.render()?.let {
            if (it.paramType() == ParamType.INLINED) {
                it.visit(
                    DSL.inline(ctx.convert(converter()).value())
                )
            } else {
                it.sql("?")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun register(ctx: BindingRegisterContext<String>) {
        ctx.statement().registerOutParameter(ctx.index(), Types.VARCHAR)
    }

    override fun set(ctx: BindingSetStatementContext<String>) {
        ctx.statement().setString(
            ctx.index(),
            ctx.convert(converter()).value()?.toString()
        )
    }

    override fun set(ctx: BindingSetSQLOutputContext<String>) {
        throw SQLFeatureNotSupportedException()
    }

    override fun get(ctx: BindingGetResultSetContext<String>) {
        ctx.convert(converter()).value(ctx.resultSet().getString(ctx.index()))
    }

    override fun get(ctx: BindingGetStatementContext<String>) {
        ctx.convert(converter()).value(ctx.statement().getString(ctx.index()))
    }

    override fun get(ctx: BindingGetSQLInputContext<String>) {
        throw SQLFeatureNotSupportedException()
    }
}
```

Generator configuration is done in XML inside the Gradle "build" file. The generated code is located inside `src/main/java/generated` while the rest of the code (including the binding) is in `src/main/kotlin`.

What could be wrong? The error log doesn't really give me any clues.

Comment: Do you have matching versions of your code generator and of the runtime library on your classpaths?

Comment: Yes. All of them are set to 3.13.5. @LukasEder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated code reads:

```java
Internal.createParameter("_2", SQLDataType.INTEGER, false, true, new LtreeBinding());
```

This means that the data type of your parameter is `INTEGER`, not `OTHER`. So your binding cannot be of type `Binding<Any, String>`. Probably, your binding was simply applied to the wrong parameter of your stored function.

If you control the function, make sure it uses named parameters, such that you can attach the binding to the proper parameter by name. Otherwise, you could try attaching it to the correct parameter by type using `<includeTypes/>` [as documented here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/).

Comment: Replacing `.*` with `ltree` in `includedTypes` helped. Thanks!